# Google Places API: Nationwide Search based on category

Tags: google-places-api

I want to build a database of location coordinates for a particular category (say movie_theatre) for the whole country (say India) and NOT nearby places. Suppose there are 5000 such places. Here is what I am planning to use:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=movie+theatre+near+india&sensor=false&key=My_key

Is there a better approach to do so? Also I cannot use the radar search as it is limited to a radius of 50km.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In specific case of movie theaters since they are based where people are settled, it makes more sense to do search in areas where the population lives; namely cities, towns, and villages.

To do this you need to get a substantial list of cities, towns, and villages from a national census bureau  (in case of India, see [here](http://censusindia.gov.in/2011-prov-results/paper2/data_files/India2/Table_3_PR_UA_Citiees_1Lakh_and_Above.pdf) and [here](http://www.censusindia.gov.in/2011census/Listofvillagesandtowns.aspx)) and then do a search for each.

Also, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026759/how-to-get-all-places-or-specific-type-of-place-such-as-a-restaurant-in-a-city?rq=1).