# Yelp API - returns only 20 results

Tags: android, yelp

I am searching since 3 days and i am not successful yet

I have integrated Yelp with reference to : https://github.com/Pretz/android-example

When i run the code with all my credentials given , I get only 20 results . Am not sure where i am going wrong . Find below the code attached

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                Yelp yelp = Yelp.getYelp(YelpSearchActivity.this);
                String businesses = yelp.search("shopping", 37.788022, -122.399797);
                try {
                    return processJson(businesses);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    return businesses;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                mSearchResultsText.setText(result);
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            }
        }.execute();

String processJson(String jsonStuff) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStuff);
        Log.e("return data", ""+json);
        JSONArray businesses = json.getJSONArray("businesses");
        ArrayList<String> businessNames = new ArrayList<String>(businesses.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < businesses.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject business = businesses.getJSONObject(i);
            businessNames.add(business.getString("name"));
        }
        return TextUtils.join("\n", businessNames);
    }
```

FYI :

//Yelp.getYelp

```
public static Yelp getYelp(Context context) {
      return new Yelp(context.getString(R.string.consumer_key), context.getString(R.string.consumer_secret),
              context.getString(R.string.token), context.getString(R.string.token_secret));
  }
```

// yelp.search

```
public String search(String term, double latitude, double longitude) {
    OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, "http://api.yelp.com/v2/search");
    request.addQuerystringParameter("term", term);
    request.addQuerystringParameter("ll", latitude + "," + longitude);
    this.service.signRequest(this.accessToken, request);
    Response response = request.send();
    return response.getBody();
  }
```

Any related answers are welcomed . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Yelp's API returns only 20 results at maximum. You're not doing anything wrong, they just limit it to 20.

[Obtaining more than 20 results with Google Places API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965847/obtaining-more-than-20-results-with-google-places-api)

However, it seems there is a [way to get up to 60 results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614258/how-to-get-20-result-from-google-places-api).